# Verify and Sign JSON Web Tokens from NodeJS to Golang and vice-versa using RSA?

Tags: node.js, go, jwt, rsa

I've generated a private key in Golang, which should be used to sign JSON Web Tokens issued to the other service coded in NodeJS.

Prior to any exchange of the tokens, NodeJS service should store the public key of the Golang client.

My problem is, I don't know how to export a rsa.PublicKey into a format which is working with NodeJS' npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken and do the same in the other direction; meaning providing the Golang client with a public key of the NodeJS service to verify incoming tokens.

Edit:

Code in question https://github.com/zarkones/XENA
Look under the file /xena-apep/main.go lines 16 and 36.

Edit2:

Here is the code in question:

```
var privateIdentificationKey = generatePrivateKey() // Generating the private key.

identify(id.String(), privateIdentificationKey.publicKey) // Won't work because of the type miss-match.

/* Generates a private key. */
func generatePrivateKey() *rsa.PrivateKey {
    secret, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 4096)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return secret
}

/* Makes Xena-Atila aware of its existence. */
func identify(id string, identificationKey string) {
    insertionPayload := []byte(`{"id":"` + id + `","identificationKey":"` + identificationKey + `","status":"ALIVE"}`)

    request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", centralizedHost+"/v1/clients", bytes.NewBuffer(insertionPayload))
    request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unable to connect to the centralized host.")
    }

    client := &http.Client{}
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    defer response.Body.Close()
}
```

Comment: According to [node-jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback) documentation, PEM encoded keys are expected. So post your Go code for the key generation, which needs to be extended for the export of the public key. You should also post the Go code for verification, which determines what format for the public key the Go side expects.

Comment: @user9014097 Thanks for your suggestion. Here is the repository https://github.com/zarkones/XENA   Look under /xena-apep/main.go, lines 16 and 35.
Will also edit my question to include the Git repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jwt.sign()` and and `jwt.verify()` method from [*node-jsonwebtoken*](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) expect PEM encoded keys. Therefore, the NodeJS side will provide the public key PEM encoded or expects a PEM encoded key (either in X.509/SPKI format or PKCS#1 format).

Key export and import is implemented in Go in the `crypto/x509` package, PEM encoding in the `encoding/pem` package, RSA in the `crypto/rsa` package.

The generation of a private and public key using the posted `GeneratePrivateKey()` method in Go is:

```go
privateKey := GeneratePrivateKey()
publicKey := &privateKey.PublicKey
```

Exporting a PEM encoded public key in X.509/SPKI format in Go is possible e.g. with:

```go
func ExportSPKIPublicKeyPEM(pubkey *rsa.PublicKey) (string){
    spkiDER, _ := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(pubkey)
    spkiPEM := pem.EncodeToMemory(
        &pem.Block{
            Type:  "PUBLIC KEY",
            Bytes: spkiDER,
        },
    )
    return string(spkiPEM)
}
```

Alternatively, a PEM encoded public key in PKCS#1 format can be exported with `MarshalPKCS1PublicKey()`. For this as `Type` `RSA PUBLIC KEY` must be specified.

The exported key can be checked with an ASN.1 parser, e.g. online with: https://lapo.it/asn1js/

The import of a PEM encoded public key in X.509/SPKI format is possible in Go e.g. with:

```go
func ImportSPKIPublicKeyPEM(spkiPEM string) (*rsa.PublicKey) {
    body, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(spkiPEM )) 
    publicKey, _ := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(body.Bytes)
    if publicKey, ok := publicKey.(*rsa.PublicKey); ok {
        return publicKey
    } else {
        return nil
    }   
}
```

With `ParsePKCS1PublicKey()` a PEM encoded public key in PKCS#1 format can be imported.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. Will improve my code based on what you've told me. Will accept the answer accordingly, soon.